Obtaining the absolute minimal, original TeX engine
I'm trying to obtain the absolute minimal, original TeX engine on my Windows 11, as close as possible to what Donald Knuth originally envisioned. I'm not looking for any pre-packaged distributions like MiKTeX or TeX Live, nor any add-ons, extensions, or third-party tools bundled with it. I want the core engine itself, in its purest form.
I'm aiming to have the smallest possible footprint on my system, to understand the fundamental workings of TeX by starting with its bare minimum, and to add components only when I need them, mirroring Knuth's approach.
I'm aware that this approach requires more manual configuration than using a full distribution, but I'm willing to invest the time to understand the system at a deeper level.
Thanks in advance for your insights and advice!

You could install just a minimal system using TeX Live so you have the core structure plus Knuth's TeX plus Metafont and CM - would that be an acceptable answer?

Your alternative is likely KerTeX, but I suspect few people have experience with it - so a TL-based approach will be easier to manage

As Joseph mentioned, KerTeX is probably what you want here. Its build system is pretty idiosyncratic, but it works well for me at least. I've only ever used it on Linux, but it claims to have Windows support.

To be really close to Knuth, I built my own version from Knuth's original tex.web source (last updated in 2021) with tangle and a Pascal compiler. Would be interested to know if anyone else follows such an approach.

@HeikoTheißen How did you manage to achieve that? Would you mind providing me with the final file?

@AnissBenthami I did, with fpcTeX.

@AnissBenthami to the second: Sure! Where should I put it?

I'm eager to see @HeikoTheißen version too...

@HeikoTheißen here is my personal email: anissbenthami@yahoo.com. Thanks in advance!

are we allowed to provide personal information on this site?

@jarnowic Let's see what happens

You must definitely try to compile TeX-fpc from CTAN: it's not that hard; all you need is to install FreePascalCompiler on Win11 and follow the instructions. I even managed to port it to DOS, just for fun.
Update
Try DEKTeX (for lack of a better name) on GitHub: I've posted the executables for DOS/Windows/Linux 32bits, with the supporting files (tfm's and plain.tex, save a DVI driver or bitmap fonts) as well.
2nd Update
I've just posted the change file (dek.ch) removing the unix specific code; try that.
The procedure is exactly as described by D.E.Knuth: compile tangle by typing fpc -otangle.exe tangle.p to bootstrap the system, and then tangle tex.web dek.ch tex.p tex.pool and fpc -otex.exe tex.p to compile the program.
Tested on Win10.
This is the diff file between Helbig's tex.ch and my dek.ch:
--- tex.ch
+++ dek.ch
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@
 
 \emergencystretch 0.6in % avoid overfull boxes 
 
-\let\maybe=\iffalse % maybe -> print all, notmaybe -> print changed modules only
+\let\notmaybe=\iffalse % maybe -> print all, notmaybe -> print changed modules only
 
 % put a mark in the left margin. (see Exercise 14.28 in The TeXbook)
 \def\marke#1{\strut\vadjust{\vbox to 0pt
@@ -136,12 +136,12 @@
 \fi
 
 [2] Change the banner line
-@x
+  @x
 known as `\TeX' [cf.~Stanford Computer Science report CS1027,
 November 1984].
 
 @d banner=='This is TeX, Version 3.141592653' {printed when \TeX\ starts}
-@y
+  @y
 known as `\TeX' [cf.~Stanford Computer Science report CS1027,
 November 1984].
 
@@ -149,7 +149,7 @@
 the banner! And take responsibility for any error.
 
 @d banner=='This is TeX-FPC, 4th ed.'
-@z
+  @z
 
 [4] program header
 @x
@@ -172,12 +172,12 @@
 @z
 
 [4] forward definition of signal catcher
-@x
+  @x
 procedure initialize; {this procedure gets things started properly}
-@y
+  @y
 procedure catch_signal(i: integer); interrupt@, forward;@t\2@>
 procedure initialize; {this procedure gets things started properly}
-@z
+  @z
 
 Since @x, @y, and @z only define a change block when they begin a
 line, you deactivate a block by indenting it (shift right) and
@@ -811,7 +811,7 @@
 @z
 
 [241]
-@x
+  @x
 @p procedure fix_date_and_time;
 begin sys_time:=12*60;
 sys_day:=4; sys_month:=7; sys_year:=1776;  {self-evident truths}
@@ -820,7 +820,7 @@
 month:=sys_month; {month of the year}
 year:=sys_year; {Anno Domini}
 end;
-@y
+  @y
 \marke X The functions |now|,  |decodedate|, and |decodetime| are provided
 by the unit |sysutils|. The command line option \.{fpc~-Fasysutils~tex.p}
 links that unit.
@@ -843,7 +843,7 @@
 fpc_decode_time(fpc_now,hh,mm,ss,ms); {current time}
 sys_time := hh*60+mm; time := sys_time; {minutes since midnight}
 end;
-@z
+  @z
 
 [360] Don't print empty lines
 @x chatty
@@ -1170,14 +1170,14 @@
    @z
 
 [1332]
-@x
+  @x
 final_end: ready_already:=0;
-@y
+  @y
 final_end:
 if want_edit then exec_editor; {user typed `\.{E}' \marke F}
 fpc_halt(history);
   {pass |history| as the exit value to the system\marke u}
-@z
+  @z
 
 [1333] print last end-of-line marker if needed
 @x
@@ -1235,10 +1235,10 @@
 @z
 
 [1379 and modules added for TeX-FPC]
-@x
+  @x
 itself will get a new section number.
 @^system dependencies@>
-@y
+  @y
 itself will get a new section number.
 
 @ \marke F If the user typed \.{E} to edit a file after confronted
@@ -1428,4 +1428,4 @@
 begin
   interrupt := i;
 end;
-@z
+  @z


The "readme" file says it is only for Unix. I have tried to compile it on my Windows 11 and failed due to some unrecognized Unix specific commands.

what I said is that I ported it to Win&DOS, and the executables are provided in the DEKTeX repository mentioned above; I think I know where I left the change file, but I shall have time to find it tonight, CST.

If you want “the absolute minimal, original TeX […] as close as possible to what Donald Knuth originally envisioned”, you can start with his TeX program, whose source is the file tex.web. It is written in WEB, which (for your purposes) is basically a macro processor on top of (a specific subset of) Pascal.
Some options you then have are:

Make some minimal changes to this tex.web (ideally via a separate "change file" as Knuth envisioned, but if you privately modify it and rename the modified file into something other than tex.web it is fine), to get it to compile with a present-day Pascal compiler. Some prior examples of this being done are TeX-GPC (last updated 2010, for GNU Pascal, and declared by the author as obsolete) and TeX-FPC (updated 2021, by the same author, for the Free Pascal compiler),

Write your own Pascal compiler to handle this dialect of Pascal,

Translate this tex.web from Pascal to C: some examples are web2w and for that matter this is in fact what is done by most so-called "TeX distributions", such as the minimal KerTeX, and also MikTeX and TeX Live.

Translate this tex.web to some other language, such as Go, Javascript, etc (all of which have been done). I have a list of several of them here (and please suggest more).


Note though that after doing all this, you will get a program, but you will still need to:

build a format file, using Knuth's plain.tex say — this means running TeX in iniTeX mode, loading plain.tex and the hyphenation patterns file, then dumping to a format file plain.fmt,

get font metric files (*.tfm), from some other TeX distribution (or available on CTAN),

the result will be a DVI file, and to process it you will need a DVI viewer (or DVI processor like dvips or dvipdfmx or dvisvgm); for this you'll need the actual font files, which you can get too.

If you want to use (say) LaTeX, you will need several extensions and changes: you may want to look into the eTeX extensions, pdfTeX, etc. Also even if you don't need LaTeX, for practical usage of even plain TeX you'll probably need more memory than the defaults in tex.web; at minimum it may be worth studying the changes made in TeX Live to TeX itself.


(For practical purposes, i.e. if your goals are not educational but simply to have “the smallest possible footprint on my system […] and to add components only when I need them”, I would recommend MikTeX, which has a “download files only when needed” mode: Just enough TeX.)

This is what I'm after but I'm shocked how complicated it is and surprised why it hasn't been done before. Making the original TeX to be an executable (.exe) isn't an exotic idea after all.

@AnissBenthami Surely someone has done it (see the link in the other answer that mentions a Win32 executable), but also a TeX executable by itself isn't much use without the font metrics and something to read the typesetting instructions (DVI). And in practice, everyone wants to use macro packages written by others, so pretty soon you have a big TeX distribution.

@AnissBenthami Remember when DEK wrote TeX, the idea of installing a piece of software was a very complex operation - tex.web is meant as a starting point for a 'local expert' to do the work to compile on their system, etc. That's very different from what most people expect today.

Just for completeness, here is my change file tex.ch and the Pascal source code of my system-specific extension texext.p. I used fpc to compile ISO Pascal.
Noteworthy points:

Certain file names (/tex/bin/tex.pool, /tex/lib/, /tex/fonts/, and /tex/fmt/plain.fmt) appear in the change file and must be changed if these files reside elsewhere on a system. This explains why I cannot simply send an executable file via mail and expect it to work for the recipient.
The external function file_search (implemented in texext.p) looks for a file to be \included or a font file to be loaded also in subdirectories. See the explanation here.
Unlike in Knuth's version, the characters at positions '177 to '377 are also used, which allows me to work with German umlaut characters (in my preferred Bitstream Charter font) in ISO-8859-1 encoding (no Unicode). These characters are mapped in the gcharter.tex format definition file.
If I remember correctly, I also had to manipulate the font files for Bitstream Charter to bring in ligatures and map the German umlaut characters.
In order to accomodate a bigger hyphenation table (for German hyphenation patterns) I have augmented the memory_word type with a fifth choice trie_halves (see here). (I know that this leaves much of the memory occupied by the mem array unused.)
Some changes alter the end-of-file handling (see here, for example). See also Length of Computer Modern TFM files.

